# Switching between two stylesheets with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

been googling for hours now ...

I have two files normal.css and dark.css and I would need a JS switch where user enables the dark mode css by a toggle but I needed it to be on all pages, I presume a local storage?

Thanks

Comment: please share your code

Comment: what tech stack you are using? simple HTML, CSS, js ?

Answer (score 1):

Either `localStorage` or `cookies` would work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
const darkMode =
{
  state: ~~localStorage.getItem("darkMode"), //convert into 0 or 1, takes less space
  ctl: null,
  css: null,

  init: function ()
  {
    this.ctl = document.getElementById("darkMode");
    if (this.ctl)
    {
      this.ctl.checked = this.state;
      this.toggle(this.state);
    }
    else
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", darkMode.init.bind(this));

  },

  toggle: function (mode)
  {
    if (mode === undefined)
      mode = ~~this.ctl.checked;

    this.state = mode;

    localStorage.setItem("darkMode", mode);
    if (mode)
    {
      if (this.css)
        return;

      this.css = document.createElement("link");
      this.css.rel = "stylesheet";
      this.css.href = "dark.css"; //path to dark.css
      document.head.appendChild(this.css);
    }
    else if (this.css)
    {
      this.css.parentNode.removeChild(this.css);
      this.css = null;
    }
  } //toggle
} //darkmode

darkMode.init();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="darkMode" type="checkbox" oninput="darkMode.toggle()">
  </body>
</html>
```

However there is another method could be used, convert your `dark.css` to be activated only when `body` has `darkmode` class.